# copy data from one dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
for index,row in dr.iterrows():
    if(dr['Level :'][index].day == today.day or dr['Level :'][index].day == tomo.day ):
        dr1 = row
    else:
        dr2 = row
```

Actually, I'm new to this pandas concept. As I copy data from `dr` dataframe to `dr2` dataframe based on condition. Those rows in `dr` dataframe are getting copied as columns in dataframe `dr2`. So, what change should I make in my code to retain `dr2` dataframe shape same as `dr` dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select row indeces, that satisfy the condition. Then use those to split the initial dataframe (I guess, you want to [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) as well):

```
dr["day"] = dr["Level :"].apply(lambda x: x.day)

ix = dr["day"].isin([today.day, tomo.day])
dr1 = dr.loc[ix].reset_index(drop=True)
dr2 = dr.loc[~ix].reset_index(drop=True)
```